# Some parts of Official 7" Touschscreen no longer registering touch

Tags: touchscreen, screen

My Touschscreen has been working fine for over a year, but since a couple of days ago some parts of the screen stopped registering touch. It started with a region in the top left, a day later the entire midsection, and right now only a small part of the bottom of the screen can register touch. The display itself is still working fine.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. I was using a Raspbian image from about a year ago, then I tried to see if a reinstall fixed the problem by using the latest Raspbian Stretch from 2017-11-29, but that didn't change anything.

Touchscreen Driver info:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.9.59-v7+/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen/rpi-ft5406.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Touchscreen driver for memory based FT5406
author:         Gordon Hollingworth
srcversion:     EEA1C213BB65978DEF5FD19
alias:          of:N*T*Crpi,rpi-ft5406C*
alias:          of:N*T*Crpi,rpi-ft5406
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.9.59-v7+ SMP mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8
```

Comment: Your touchscreen might be dieing. If it has been dropped in the past, this may cause some problems.